# Dollar basis calculation. Where do I miss the point?

Tags: fx, cross-currency-basis

I read that recently, due to the covid-19, the pressure on the dollar market has risen significantly on the demand side. That is why the dollar basis became largly negativ.

https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2020-03-17/how-cross-currency-basis-swaps-show-funding-stress-quicktake
https://www.bis.org/publ/bisbull01.pdf

I tried to replicate this calculation for a university Essay. From the spot and 3M fwd rate I calculated the implied dollar interest rate. Then for the basis from this I extracted the 3M USD LIBOR. 
However my graph is looking like this:[image]
It seems to me pretty the same, but on the positive side. Do I misinterpret it, if I say, it shows the premium which I have to pay, due I don't have access to direct us market, so I finance through the off-shore dollar market? 
Could someone explain me, whether I misunderstood something or am I using the wrong dataset. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basis is almost always calculated on the non-usd leg - which explains why your signs are the wrong way around.

Comment: Thank you, meanwhile I also found that out. Yeah, that's correct, it explains it. I don't know, why I can't upvote you, but thank you.